# How generate planes parallel to the camera view plane?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, webgl2

I am trying to do texture-based volume reneding with a 3D texture. I just mapped this texture to a stack of planes but I need to have these planes parallel to the camera to avoid bad visualization when the camera is moved. Basically I want to make a viewport-aligned slices. I have been trying but I don't know how to start. first of all I want just one parallel slice.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The plane's normal is just the camera's direction, and two convenient basis vectors in the plane are given by the camera's up and right vectors.

Comment: Thank you! I will use the camera direction and one known point of the plane to get the plane eq.